# Is it possible to forbid foreign keys in different tables to reference the same row?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two 3 tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "items" (
    "key"   TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "name_key"  TEXT,
    "base_price"    INTEGER,
    "description_key"   TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("key")
)
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE "consumable_items" (
    "key"   TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "item_key"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "scope" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "only_menu" BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("key"),
    FOREIGN KEY("item_key") REFERENCES "items"("key")
)
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE "weapons" (
    "key"   TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "item_key"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "name_key"  TEXT,
    "type"  TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY("item_key") REFERENCES "items"("key"),
    FOREIGN KEY("type") REFERENCES "weapon_types"("key"),
    PRIMARY KEY("key")
)
```

I have some kind of "inheritance" relationship here.

`consumable_items` references `items` and `weapons` also references `items` for storing common properties. between all items.

I would like to forbid the creation of a `consumable_item` if a `weapon` already exists with the same foreign key and vice versa

For example:

If I have the following item:

```
INSERT INTO "main"."items" ("key", "name_key", "base_price", "description_key") VALUES ('excalibur', 'excalibur', '800000', 'excalibur');
```

EITHER `consumable_items` can reference `excalibur` OR `weapons` can reference it, but not both at the same time.

Is that possible with SQL(ite)?

Comment: Table inheritance can be concrete (parent table always have a child) or abstract (parent may not always have a child). It can also be exclusive (only one child) or inclusive (can have different children). You seem to want to model concrete exclusive inheritance. Is that correct?

Comment: I think so, yes.